# 2 dhcp server with one pool

Tags: networking, router, lan, dhcp

I want to know if there is an option to have two DHCP servers with one pool. The reason for this unorthodox setup is, I have two router in remote locations on the same LAN (10.0.0.0) And sometimes, the main router is down, and I cannot reboot it for sometime. But I want to be able to still use the network with the router that is up but not running DHCP and therefore new devices cannot join in. I can't create two lans because one of my routers does not support WAN. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could run `isc-dhcp-server` on two instances of Linux somewhere on your LAN, and disable DHCP on your router - [it supports a two-node failover configuration](https://kb.isc.org/article/AA-00502/0/A-Basic-Guide-to-Configuring-DHCP-Failover.html).